# implement multiple instance support on jquery autosuggest plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, autosuggest

Hi below is my code for a jquery auto suggest plugin I am using. I am wondering what changes I would need to make to implement mutiple instance support. (having autosuggest for more than one form on the same page. Thank you.

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    autoSuggest : function(options){
        var defaults = {
            ajaxFilePath : "",
            ajaxParams   : "",
            autoFill     : false,
            iwidth       : "auto",
            opacity      : "0.9",
            ilimit       : "10",
            idHolder     : "",
            match        : "starts"
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);      

        var ajaxFilePath = options.ajaxFilePath;
        var ajaxParams   = options.ajaxParams;
        var autoFill     = options.autoFill;
        var width        = options.iwidth;
        var opacity      = options.opacity;
        var limit        = options.ilimit;
        var idHolder     = options.idHolder;
        var match        = options.match;

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);

            obj.keyup(function(event){
                var p = obj;
                var offset = p.offset();
                var keyword = obj.val();

                if(keyword.length)
                 {
                     if(event.keyCode != 40 && event.keyCode != 38 && event.keyCode != 13)
                     {
                         if(ajaxFilePath != "")
                         {
                             $.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url: ajaxFilePath,
                               data: "data="+keyword+"&limit="+limit+"&match="+match+"&"+ajaxParams+"&getId=1",
                               success: function(responce){ 
                                if(responce != 0)
                                {
                                  var vals = responce.split("|"); 
                                  if(vals.length)
                                  {
                                      optionList = "<ul class=\"list\">";
                                      for(i=0;i<vals.length;i++)
                                      {
                                         valuenid = vals[i].split("-");
                                         myText = valuenid[1]; 
                                         myId = valuenid[0]; 
                                         // trim string to remove extra white spaces around the text
                                         myText = myText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

                                         if(match == "starts")
                                             // check if string starts with given characters
                                             myText = myText.replace( myText.match("^"+keyword), '<span class="highlighted">'+keyword+'</span>');
                                         else if(match == "ends")
                                             //alert(myText.replace(/(.*)keyword/, "<b>hi</b>"));
                                             myText = myText.replace (new RegExp( keyword + '$'), '<span class="highlighted">'+keyword+'</span>');
                                         else if(match == "contains")
                                             myText = myText.replace( new RegExp(keyword, "i" ), '<span class="highlighted">'+keyword+'</span>');

                                         if(idHolder != "" && idHolder != null)
                                            optionList += "<li><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\""+myId+"\">"+myText+"</a></li>";
                                         else       
                                            optionList += "<li><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">"+myText+"</a></li>";
                                      }
                                      optionList += "</ul>";

                                  }
                                  if($(".ajax_response").html() == null)
                                  {
                                      var id = obj.attr("id");
                                      // initialization
                                      $(".dropdown").append("<div class='ajax_response'></div>")
                                      .css("left",parseInt($("#"+id).offset().left))
                                      .css("top",parseInt(offset.top + obj.height() + 3))
                                      .css("opacity",opacity)
                                      .html(optionList).css("display","block");////REMEMBER

                                      // set responce div width
                                      if(width == "auto")
                                          $(".ajax_response").css("width",parseInt(obj.width()) + 2);
                                      else  
                                          $(".ajax_response").css("width",parseInt(width + 2));
                                  }
                                  else
                                      $(".ajax_response").html(optionList).css("display","block");
                                }
                                else
                                  $(".list").css("display","none");
                               }
                             });
                         }
                         else
                             alert("Ajax file path not provided");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        $(".list li .selected").removeClass("selected");
                        switch (event.keyCode)
                        {
                         case 40:
                         {
                              found = 0;
                              $(".list li").each(function(){
                                 if($(this).attr("class") == "selected")
                                    found = 1;
                              });
                              if(found == 1)
                              {
                                var sel = $(".list li[class='selected']");
                                // check if his is a last element in the list
                                // if so then add selected class to the first element in the list
                                if(sel.next().text() == "")                 
                                    $(".list li:first").addClass("selected");
                                else
                                    sel.next().addClass("selected");
                                // remove class selected from previous item
                                sel.removeClass("selected");
                              }
                              else
                                $(".list li:first").addClass("selected");
                          }
                         break;
                         case 38:
                         {
                              found = 0;
                              $(".list li").each(function(){
                                 if($(this).attr("class") == "selected")
                                    found = 1;
                              });
                              if(found == 1)
                              {
                                var sel = $(".list li[class='selected']");
                                // check if his is a last element in the list
                                // if so then add selected class to the first element in the list
                                if(sel.prev().text() == "")                 
                                    $(".list li:last").addClass("selected");
                                else
                                    sel.prev().addClass("selected");
                                // remove class selected from previous item
                                sel.removeClass("selected");
                              }
                              else
                                $(".list li:last").addClass("selected");
                         }
                         break;
                         case 13:
                            str = $(".list li[class='selected']").text();
                            obj.val(str);
                            // store id of the selected option
                            if(idHolder != "" && idHolder != null)
                                $("#"+idHolder).val($(".list li[class='selected'] a").attr("id"));
                            $(".list").hide();
                         break;
                        }
                        // if autoFill option is true then fill selected value in textbox
                        if(autoFill)
                        {
                            str = $(".list li[class='selected']").text();
                            obj.val(str);
                        }
                     }
                 }
                else
                    // if there is no character in the text field then remove the suggestion box 
                    $(".list").hide();
            });

            // prevent form submission on enter key press
            //obj.keypress(function(event){
             //if(event.keyCode == "13")
                // return false;
            //});   

            $(".list li").live("mouseover",function () {
                $(".list li[class='selected']").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                // if autoFill option is true then fill selected value in textbox
                if(autoFill)
                {
                    str = $(".list li[class='selected']").text();
                    obj.val(str);
                }
            });
            $(".list li").live("click",function () {
                str = $(".list li[class='selected']").text();
                obj.val(str);
                // store id of the selected option
                if(idHolder != "" && idHolder != null)
                    $("#"+idHolder).val($("li[class='selected'] a").attr("id"));
                $(".list").hide();                  
            });
            $(document).click(function(){
                if($(".list").css("display") == "block")
                    $(".list").hide();
            });
            $(document).keyup(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 9)
                {
                    str = $(".list li[class='selected']").text();
                    obj.val(str);
                    // store id of the selected option
                    if(idHolder != "" && idHolder != null)
                        $("#"+idHolder).val($(".list li[class='selected'] a").attr("id"));
                    $(".list").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    }
}); 
}) (jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern supports multiple instances: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.highly-configurable.plugin.boilerplate.js